# Closing and opening processes by "Hotkey"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
from time import sleep

def o1():
    while True:
        print("1 : )")
        sleep(1)

def o2():
    while True:
        print("2 : )")
        sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=o1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=o2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    def close():
        print("close o1")
        p1.join() #the process does not end as a result

    def start():
        print("start o1")
        try:
            p1.start()
        except AssertionError:
            print("Nothing")

    import keyboard
    keyboard.add_hotkey('q', close)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('e', start) #after q, nothing happens trying to press "e"
```

I need to close the process and reopen it by hotkey. (I did two processes in the code, as this fully reflects the program in which I need this function)

I'm sorry for my english : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `p1.join()` patiently waits for `p1` to finish by itself -- which it won't do, since it's running an infinite loop. Use `p1.terminate()` here.

Secondly, you can't re-start a process that has finished (in fact, that is the AssertionError you are erroneously catching). There are two solutions here:

1. `suspend` and `resume` the process, rather than terminating it
2. Start an entirely new process in its place

Here is my implementation of the second approach. Due to a [multiprocessing quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42383397/2111778) I had to split my code across multiple files:

**procs.py**

```py
from time import sleep

def o1():
    while True:
        print("1 : )")
        sleep(1)

def o2():
    while True:
        print("2 : )")
        sleep(1)
```

**main.py**

```py
from procs import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=o1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=o2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    def close():
        print("close o1")
        p1.terminate()

    def start():
        global p1
        if p1.is_alive():
            return
        print("start o1")
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=o1)
        p1.start()

    import keyboard
    keyboard.add_hotkey('q', close)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('e', start)
```

Comment: It clears the console when I start a new process. Can I fix this somehow? And this is how it works, thanks!)

Comment: Does it clear the console when you start a new process with 'e' or a new main process? It doesn't clear the console _for me_ when I press 'e' (I'm using PyCharm)

Comment: I just put it in my code right away, this is probably the problem. I will try to fix it myself.