# Python multiprocessing queue not showing results

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run a separate Python Process and store the result in the queue. I can extract the result in two ways: either run `queue.get()` just once or use a while loop and iterate over queue until it`s empty.
In the code below first method is used if `first=True` and second method is used if `first=False`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def foo1(queue):
    queue.put(1)


def main(first=False):

    queue = Queue()

    p = Process(target=foo1, args=(queue,))
    p.start()

    if first:
        a = queue.get()
        print(a)
    else:
        while not queue.empty():
            print(queue.get())

    p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Question**: Why does first method print `1` correctly and second does not ? Aren`t they supposed to be equal ?

I am using Windows 10. I noticed this behavior in both interactive console and shell terminal.

**Note**: Due to the bug mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror/42383397) I have to run the code as one script.

Comment: The queue is empty at the beginning, until `foo1` is executed, and that happens after a delay. So, you have no way of differentiating between "not filled yet" and "already emptied".

Comment: would you like to post as answer ? I ll accept