# Unable to use pool.apply_async to aggregate results with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Let's say I have the following function:

```
def fetch_num():
    x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000000) # choose a number
    for i in range(5000000): # do some calculations
        j = i ** 2
    return x # return a result
```

This function picks a random number, then does some calculations, and returns it.

I would like to create a large list, containing all of these results. The catch is, that I don't want to process the same number twice, and I want to use `multiprocessing` to make that quicker.

I've tried the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
from parallelizing_defs import fetch_num
import os
os.system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % os.getpid())
if __name__ == '__main__':


    n = 10 # number of numbers that I want to gather

    def collect_result(result): # a callback function - only append if it is not in the results list
        if result not in results:
            results.append(result)
            pbar.update(1) # this is just for the fancy progress bar

    def error_callback(e):
        raise e

    pool = mp.Pool(6) # create 6 workers

    global results # initialize results list
    results = []
    pbar = tqdm(total=n) # initialize a progress bar
    while len(results) < n: # work until enough results have been accumulated
        pool.apply_async(fetch_num, args=(), callback=collect_result, error_callback=error_callback)
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()
```

Notes:

- the function `fetch_num` is imported from a different python file since I understand that it doesn't work within the same file from this issue [Multiprocessing example giving AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror)
- the weird `os` line, I added after reading this issue: [Why does multiprocessing use only a single core after I import numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639779/why-does-multiprocessing-use-only-a-single-core-after-i-import-numpy)

My problem is:

- The loop doesn't stop, it goes on forever.
- The iterations are not faster, it doesn't seem to be using more than one core.

I've tried a bunch of other configurations, but it doesn't seem to work. This sounds like a very common situation but I haven't been able to find an example of that particular problem.
Any ideas as to why these behaviours take place would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues. First, you need to include `numpy`. But your big problem is:

```
while len(results) < n: # work until enough results have been accumulated
    pool.apply_async(fetch_num, args=(), callback=collect_result, error_callback=error_callback)
```

You can be submitting these jobs with calls to `apply_async` faster than the results are returned and end up submitting way too many jobs. You need to submit exactly `n` jobs and take care of ensuring that duplicate results are not returned in `fetch_num`. The way to do that is to use a sharable set that holds all previously generated numbers. Unfortunately, sharable sets do not exist. But we do have sharable dictionaries that can serve the purpose. We therefore initialize each process in the pool with a proxy pointer to the sharable dictionary and a lock to serialize access to the dictionary.

It is true that process pools functions sucg as `fetch_num` must be imported for but *only if you are running under something like `jupyter notebook`*. If you are running the program "normally" from the command line, this is not required. I have therefore included the source inline so you might see it. I have also added a print statement so that you can see that all 6 processes are running in parallel.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm


def pool_init(the_dict, l):
    global num_set, the_lock
    num_set = the_dict
    the_lock = l


def fetch_num():
    the_lock.acquire()
    print('fetch_num')
    while True:
        # get
        x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000000) # choose a number
        if x not in num_set:
            num_set[x] = True
            break
    the_lock.release()

    for i in range(5000000): # do some calculations
        j = i ** 2
    return x # return a result



if __name__ == '__main__':

    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        the_dict = manager.dict()
        the_lock = mp.Lock()
        n = 10 # number of numbers that I want to gather

        results = []
        def collect_result(result):
            results.append(result)
            pbar.update(1) # this is just for the fancy progress bar

        pool = mp.Pool(6, initializer=pool_init, initargs=(the_dict, the_lock)) # create 6 workers
        pbar = tqdm(total=n) # initialize a progress bar
        for _ in range(n):
            pool.apply_async(fetch_num, args=(), callback=collect_result)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print()
        print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you need to generate the number in the function doing the processing? Both Python and NumPy have ways to sample without replacement so as to feed a bunch of unique random integers to your process pool without them needing to worry about acquiring and releasing locks.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
>>> rng = np.random.default_rng()
>>> randoms = rng.choice(1000000, size=(10,), replace=False)
>>> randoms
array([908648, 947502, 510774, 272587, 362679, 529124,  42039, 912716,
       921618, 581853])
>>> with ProcessPoolExecutor() as p:
...     results = p.map(process_num, randoms)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm aware of that option, but it's just an example to serve the generality of the question. I'm handling a data type that I sample, and it doesn't have that 'replace=False' option, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `error_callback` to display the error from the subprocess and either decrements the expected results (so you don't loop forever) or pushes the error up to crash the script.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question, and added the `error_callback`. It seems though that no error occurs, since nothing changed.