# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'InsertNews' on <module '__main__'

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pymongo

I am trying to write a program scrape website content. The script seems to run for a while but stops after a couple of iterations

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 581, in _terminate_pool
    cls._help_stuff_finish(inqueue, task_handler, len(pool))
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 568, in _help_stuff_finish
    inqueue._reader.recv()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'InsertNews' on <module '__main__' from 'c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft visual studio\\2019\\common7\\ide\\extensions\\microsoft\\python\\core\\debugpy\\__main__.py'>
```

Here is the script that I am trying to run

```
from boilerpy3 import extractors
import pymongo
import multiprocessing as mp


def InsertNews(newsite, symbol):
        
        print(symbol)
        print(newsite)
        extractor = extractors.ArticleExtractor()
        try:
            content = extractor.get_content_from_url(newsite)
        except Exception:
            pass
        print(content)
        record={symbol,content}
        mydb["StocksPressRelease"].insert_one(record)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("started")
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://un:pwd@cluster0.subkd.azure.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority&connectTimeoutMS=900000")
    mydb = myclient["db"]
    mycol = mydb["Stocks"]

    for x in mycol.find({},{"_id": 0, "symbol":1, "newsite": 1 }):
        results = pool.apply_async(InsertNews,args=(x["newsite"],x["symbol"]))
    
    pool.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried running your script from a cmd prompt? Visual Studio standing between you and your code might be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror), the multiprocessing Pool doesn't work as intended for objects not defined in an imported module. You can try writing your **InsertNews** function in a separate module and then import it.

File: **news.py**

```
from boilerpy3 import extractors

def InsertNews(newsite, symbol):            
        print(symbol)
        print(newsite)
        extractor = extractors.ArticleExtractor()
        try:
            content = extractor.get_content_from_url(newsite)
        except Exception:
            pass
        print(content)
```

File: **main.py**

```
import pymongo
import multiprocessing as mp
import news

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("started")
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://un:pwd@cluster0.subkd.azure.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority&connectTimeoutMS=900000")
    mydb = myclient["db"]
    mycol = mydb["Stocks"]

    for x in mycol.find({},{"_id": 0, "symbol":1, "newsite": 1 }):
        results = pool.apply_async(news.InsertNews,args=(x["newsite"],x["symbol"]))
    
    pool.close()
```

Comment: "Pool doesn't work as intended for objects not defined in an imported module." That's not really correct. multiprocessing is not designed for use with interactive sessions which is always the case with IPython.

Comment: @Aaron, it is correct what you mentioned about the multiprocessing module not working with IPython. What I wrote was just a text quoted from another SO post. But from what I have read on other posts, the only way to overcome this problem is by using the multiprocess module or by externalizing the code in another module.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror