# Multiprocessing with Pool doesn't use all available CPU

Tags: python, matrix, multiprocessing, generator, python-multiprocessing

I have some code that needs to work through a huge set of matrices (all `5` by `10` binary matrices in [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form), with no zero rows) and either accept or reject each matrix depending on whether it satisfies some conditions. Since there's a lot to get through, I'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed things up. Here's roughly what my code currently looks like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def check_valid(matrix):
    # Perform some checks and things
    if all_checks_passed:
        return matrix.copy()
    return None

subgroups = []

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    subgroups_iter = pool.imap(
        check_valid,
        get_rref_matrices(5),
        chunksize=1000
    )

    for item in subgroups_iter:
        if item is not None:
            subgroups.append(item)
```

`get_rref_matrices` is a generator function that recursively finds all the rref matrices (I'm not sure if this function is causing any issues). The full code for this function is [here](https://gist.github.com/MrLatinNerd/eb77e738729723ed93ec640b9bd9e1cd), if that's of interest.

When I run the program, it seems to be very slow (hardly any faster than a single process) and the CPU usage is only about 10%. I've previously run code that has maxed out my CPU, so I'm stumped as to why this code isn't running faster.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I'm thinking there could be a bottleneck of some kind, and that the CPU is not the bottleneck. Or maybe it's that some shared resources are locking out all other threads? Just a few guesses.

Comment: Have you tried a smaller chunk size? 1000 seems a lot. Also, what's the approximate total number of matrices?

Comment: See [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: In particular `get_rref_matrices` seems like a likely candidate to be a bottleneck as it's a generator and not a precomputed list.

Comment: Yeah, the only work you seem to be passing to the worker processes is `matrix.copy()`, almost certainly, that is not the bottleneck

Comment: @RandomDavis I just tried profiling the code, but I keep getting this error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'check_valid' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Comment: @MrLatinNerd does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror) help with that error? Also I meant that you could just profile the single-process version since that'd be easier I'm sure.

Comment: If your generator yielded  a 1000 or fewer items, for example, with a *chunksize* value of 1000, you would in effect not be multiprocessing at all; one process in the pool would be grabbing all the submitted items as a single chunk.