# How to use multiprocessing pool for Pandas apply function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I want to use pool for Pandas data frames.
I tried as follows, but the following error occurs.
Can't I use pool for Series?

```
from multiprocessing import pool

split = np.array_split(split,4)
pool = Pool(processes=4)
df = pd.concat(pool.map(split['Test'].apply(lambda x : test(x)), split))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The error message is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Have you tried the [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter) package for this?

Comment: I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def test(x):
    return x * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Demo dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': range(100)})

    # Extract the Series and split into chunk
    split = np.array_split(df['Test'], 4)

    # Parallel processing
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        data = pool.map(test, split)

    # Concatenate results
    out = pd.concat(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Test
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
..   ...
95    95
96    96
97    97
98    98
99    99

[100 rows x 1 columns]

>>> out
0       0
1       2
2       4
3       6
4       8
     ... 
95    190
96    192
97    194
98    196
99    198
Name: Test, Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it didnt't work for me..

Comment: Maybe you could explain why? What is the error message?

Comment: File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'test' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Comment: The above error occurs when I execute the code you gave me an example of and when I execute my code.

Comment: Did you rename the `test` function?