# Simulating - speeding up script in python

Tags: python, profiling

I have the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.stats as sp
    
raw = pd.read_csv("ELT_RawData.csv")

raw["weight"] = raw["RATE"] / np.sum(raw["RATE"])
MU = np.sum(raw["RATE"])

poisson = sp.poisson(mu=MU)
n_simulations = 10000
xs = 5e6
lim = 10e6

result = np.empty((n_simulations))

for i in range(n_simulations):
    no_clm = poisson.rvs(size=1)
    
    #simulate beta distribution
    
    sampled_events = raw.sample(n=no_clm,weights=raw["weight"])
    
    #calculate params for beta distribution
    a_1 = ( (sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"] / (sampled_events["STDDEVI"]+sampled_events["STDDEVC"]))**2*(1 - sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"]/sampled_events["EXPVALUE"]) - \
             sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"] / sampled_events["EXPVALUE"] )
        
    b_1 = a_1*(sampled_events["EXPVALUE"]/sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"]-1)
    
    #simulate from said distribution
    clm_sev = np.array(sp.beta(a_1,b_1).rvs(no_clm)*sampled_events["EXPVALUE"])
    
    #apply features
    xol_loss = np.clip(a=clm_sev-xs,a_min=0,a_max=lim)
    
    #store result
    result[i] = xol_loss.sum()
    
result.mean()
```

The `raw` data can be read like this:

```
raw = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'EVENTID': {0: 'A_0', 1: 'A_1', 2: 'A_2', 3: 'A_3', 4: 'A_4', 5: 'A_5', 6: 'A_6', 7: 'A_7', 8: 'A_8', 9: 'A_9', 10: 'A_10', 11: 'A_11', 12: 'A_12', 13: 'A_13', 14: 'A_14', 15: 'A_15', 16: 'A_16', 17: 'A_17', 18: 'A_18', 19: 'A_19', 20: 'A_20', 21: 'A_21', 22: 'A_22', 23: 'A_23', 24: 'A_24', 25: 'A_25', 26: 'A_26', 27: 'A_27', 28: 'A_28', 29: 'A_29', 30: 'A_30', 31: 'A_31', 32: 'A_32', 33: 'A_33', 34: 'A_34', 35: 'A_35', 36: 'A_36', 37: 'A_37', 38: 'A_38', 39: 'A_39', 40: 'A_40', 41: 'A_41', 42: 'A_42', 43: 'A_43', 44: 'A_44', 45: 'A_45', 46: 'A_46', 47: 'A_47', 48: 'A_48', 49: 'A_49', 50: 'A_50', 51: 'A_51', 52: 'A_52', 53: 'A_53', 54: 'A_54', 55: 'A_55', 56: 'A_56', 57: 'A_57', 58: 'A_58', 59: 'A_59', 60: 'A_60', 61: 'A_61', 62: 'A_62', 63: 'A_63', 64: 'A_64', 65: 'A_65', 66: 'A_66', 67: 'A_67', 68: 'A_68', 69: 'A_69', 70: 'A_70', 71: 'A_71', 72: 'A_72', 73: 'A_73', 74: 'A_74', 75: 'A_75', 76: 'A_76', 77: 'A_77', 78: 'A_78', 79: 'A_79', 80: 'A_80', 81: 'A_81', 82: 'A_82', 83: 'A_83', 84: 'A_84', 85: 'A_85', 86: 'A_86', 87: 'A_87', 88: 'A_88', 89: 'A_89', 90: 'A_90', 91: 'A_91', 92: 'A_92', 93: 'A_93', 94: 'A_94', 95: 'A_95', 96: 'A_96', 97: 'A_97', 98: 'A_98', 99: 'A_99', 100: 'A_100', 101: 'A_101', 102: 'A_102', 103: 'A_103', 104: 'A_104', 105: 'A_105', 106: 'A_106', 107: 'A_107', 108: 'A_108', 109: 'A_109', 110: 'A_110', 111: 'A_111', 112: 'A_112', 113: 'A_113', 114: 'A_114', 115: 'A_115', 116: 'A_116', 117: 'A_117', 118: 'A_118', 119: 'A_119', 120: 'A_120', 121: 'A_121', 122: 'A_122', 123: 'A_123', 124: 'A_124', 125: 'A_125', 126: 'A_126', 127: 'A_127', 128: 'A_128', 129: 'A_129', 130: 'A_130', 131: 'A_131', 132: 'A_132', 133: 'A_133', 134: 'A_134', 135: 'A_135', 136: 'A_136', 137: 'A_137', 138: 'A_138', 139: 'A_139', 140: 'A_140', 141: 'A_141', 142: 'A_142', 143: 'A_143', 144: 'A_144', 145: 'A_145', 146: 'A_146', 147: 'A_147', 148: 'A_148', 149: 'A_149', 150: 'A_150', 151: 'A_151', 152: 'A_152', 153: 'A_153', 154: 'A_154', 155: 'A_155', 156: 'A_156', 157: 'A_157', 158: 'A_158', 159: 'A_159', 160: 'A_160', 161: 'A_161', 162: 'A_162', 163: 'A_163', 164: 'A_164', 165: 'A_165', 166: 'A_166', 167: 'A_167', 168: 'A_168', 169: 'A_169', 170: 'A_170', 171: 'A_171', 172: 'A_172', 173: 'A_173', 174: 'A_174', 175: 'A_175', 176: 'A_176', 177: 'A_177', 178: 'A_178', 179: 'A_179', 180: 'A_180', 181: 'A_181', 182: 'A_182', 183: 'A_183', 184: 'A_184', 185: 'A_185', 186: 'A_186', 187: 'A_187', 188: 'A_188', 189: 'A_189', 190: 'A_190', 191: 'A_191', 192: 'A_192', 193: 'A_193', 194: 'A_194', 195: 'A_195', 196: 'A_196', 197: 'A_197'}, 'RATE': {0: 0.001013797, 1: 0.001013797, 2: 0.001013797, 3:
0.001013797, 4: 0.001013797, 5: 0.001013797, 6: 0.001013797, 7: 0.001013797, 8: 0.001013797, 9: 0.001013797, 10: 0.001013797, 11: 0.001013797, 12: 0.001013797, 13: 0.001013797, 14: 0.001013797, 15: 0.001013797, 16: 0.001013797, 17: 0.001013797, 18: 0.001013797, 19: 0.001013797, 20: 0.001013797, 21: 0.001013797, 22: 0.001013797, 23: 0.001013797, 24: 0.001013797, 25: 0.001013797, 26: 0.001013797, 27: 0.001013797, 28: 0.001013797, 29: 0.001013797, 30: 0.001013797, 31: 0.001013797, 32: 0.001013797, 33: 0.001013797, 34: 0.001013797, 35: 0.001013797, 36: 0.001013797, 37: 0.001013797, 38: 0.001013797, 39: 0.001013797, 40: 0.001013797, 41: 0.001013797, 42: 0.001013797, 43: 0.001013797, 44: 0.001013797, 45: 0.001013797, 46: 0.001013797, 47: 0.001013797, 48: 0.001013797, 49: 0.001013797, 50: 0.001013797, 51: 0.001013797, 52: 0.001013797, 53: 0.001013797, 54: 0.001013797, 55: 0.001013797, 56: 0.001013797, 57: 0.001013797, 58: 0.001013797, 59: 0.001013797, 60: 0.001013797, 61: 0.001013797, 62: 0.001013797, 63: 0.001013797, 64: 0.001013797, 65: 0.001013797, 66: 0.001013797, 67: 0.001013797, 68: 0.001013797, 69: 0.001013797, 70: 0.001013797, 71: 0.001013797, 72: 0.001013797, 73: 0.001013797, 74: 0.001013797, 75: 0.001013797, 76: 0.001013797, 77: 0.001013797, 78: 0.001013797, 79: 0.001013797, 80: 0.001013797, 81: 0.001013797, 82: 0.001013797, 83: 0.001013797, 84: 0.001013797, 85: 0.001013797, 86: 0.001013797, 87: 0.001013797, 88: 0.001013797, 89: 0.001013797, 90: 0.001013797, 91: 0.001013797, 92: 0.001013797, 93: 0.001013797, 94: 0.001013797, 95: 0.001013797, 96: 0.001013797, 97: 0.001013797, 98: 0.001013797, 99: 0.001013797, 100: 0.001013797, 101: 0.001013797, 102: 0.001013797, 103: 0.001013797, 104: 0.001013797, 105: 0.001013797, 106:
0.001013797, 107: 0.001013797, 108: 0.001013797, 109: 0.001013797, 110: 0.001013797, 111: 0.001013797, 112: 0.001013797, 113:
0.001013797, 114: 0.001013797, 115: 0.001013797, 116: 0.001013797, 117: 0.001013797, 118: 0.001013797, 119: 0.001013797, 120:
0.001013797, 121: 0.001013797, 122: 0.001013797, 123: 0.001013797, 124: 0.001013797, 125: 0.001013797, 126: 0.001013797, 127:
0.001013797, 128: 0.001013797, 129: 0.001013797, 130: 0.001013797, 131: 0.001013797, 132: 0.001013797, 133: 0.001013797, 134:
0.001013797, 135: 0.001013797, 136: 0.001013797, 137: 0.001013797, 138: 0.001013797, 139: 0.001013797, 140: 0.001448281, 141:
0.001448281, 142: 0.001448281, 143: 0.001448281, 144: 0.001448281, 145: 0.001448281, 146: 0.001448281, 147: 0.001448281, 148:
0.001448281, 149: 0.001448281, 150: 0.001448281, 151: 0.001448281, 152: 0.001448281, 153: 0.001448281, 154: 0.001448281, 155:
0.001448281, 156: 0.001448281, 157: 0.001448281, 158: 0.001448281, 159: 0.001448281, 160: 0.001448281, 161: 0.001448281, 162:
0.001448281, 163: 0.001448281, 164: 0.001448281, 165: 0.001448281, 166: 0.001448281, 167: 0.001448281, 168: 0.001448281, 169:
0.001448281, 170: 0.001448281, 171: 0.001448281, 172: 0.001448281, 173: 0.001448281, 174: 0.001448281, 175: 0.001448281, 176:
0.001448281, 177: 0.001448281, 178: 0.001448281, 179: 0.001448281, 180: 0.001448281, 181: 0.001448281, 182: 0.001448281, 183:
0.001448281, 184: 0.001448281, 185: 0.001448281, 186: 0.001448281, 187: 0.001448281, 188: 0.001448281, 189: 0.00551956, 190: 0.00551956, 191: 0.00551956, 192: 0.00551956, 193: 0.00551956, 194: 0.00551956, 195: 0.00551956, 196: 0.00551956, 197: 0.00551956}, 'PERSPVALUE': {0:
27068207.53, 1: 16139432.33, 2: 16612880.78, 3: 15223154.23, 4: 13329725.56, 5: 12639283.46, 6: 14398548.59, 7: 26784197.78, 8: 17256618.07, 9: 11657837.22, 10: 12252501.6, 11: 24904672.14, 12: 10258771.29, 13: 11502035.81, 14: 11532813.52, 15: 17269205.53, 16: 12693599.88, 17: 14536926.96, 18: 9539792.21, 19: 7971501.616, 20: 8244881.149, 21: 6003459.601, 22: 4222915.124, 23: 20863174.85, 24: 11029584.79, 25: 7584126.22, 26: 15145416.28, 27: 7329721.345, 28: 12266029.43, 29: 5688784.226, 30: 4068513.751, 31: 15281888.13, 32: 11922537.91, 33: 4396013.28, 34: 2671760.764, 35: 1906603.424, 36: 3873159.464, 37: 13311419.88, 38: 5283934.11, 39: 11110692.34, 40: 9648885.591, 41: 6027654.746, 42: 6992837.358, 43: 4696371.296, 44: 4937007.527, 45: 5167548.583, 46: 1457331.046, 47: 4243265.898, 48: 5344537.717, 49: 5348237.625, 50: 2302969.738, 51: 3590748.252, 52: 4917922.812, 53: 6939780.743, 54: 3336948.716, 55: 2726471.252, 56: 6178289.029, 57: 2871203.944, 58: 3419346.8, 59: 2832834.938, 60: 5663559.289, 61: 3585861.103, 62: 3734039.93, 63: 3187926.465, 64: 4676672.934, 65: 4202429.132, 66: 825265.2121, 67: 2050863.214, 68: 2548953.176, 69: 4358778.251, 70: 2543793.804, 71: 3137277.456, 72: 3736864.886, 73: 1833556.979, 74: 2190284.487, 75: 1020392.457, 76: 3409046.421, 77: 3680362.683, 78: 3486760.876, 79: 3575292.65, 80: 3047082.934, 81: 3569162.709, 82: 2822371.667, 83: 3288314.142, 84: 2309749.76, 85: 274178.2925, 86: 2970113.437, 87: 2375593.126, 88: 2169592.635, 89: 2445757.474, 90: 1153270.295, 91: 843862.5591, 92: 1517770.688, 93: 3120120.296, 94: 1908922.549, 95: 949387.4377, 96: 555355.6563, 97: 1749621.443, 98: 1635296.659, 99: 1266107.641, 100: 1650184.057, 101: 1460167.669, 102: 1606946.205, 103: 1512397.297, 104: 1341212.516, 105: 894387.1565, 106: 1169059.447, 107:
1228485.862, 108: 369173.9589, 109: 960353.85, 110: 1022879.73, 111: 637366.6611, 112: 707716.8876, 113: 933317.7985, 114: 890590.3473, 115: 812629.496, 116: 671498.5074, 117: 648790.1261, 118: 738000.0, 119: 659490.5537, 120: 685486.6873, 121: 619717.8567, 122:
453714.5127, 123: 577421.4298, 124: 1142637.061, 125: 505567.7285, 126: 509675.9037, 127: 501422.4293, 128: 362900.5682, 129:
407749.7206, 130: 426971.0817, 131: 281477.1802, 132: 424598.9225, 133: 401336.4033, 134: 363427.0346, 135: 365667.4665, 136:
306451.1672, 137: 225000.0, 138: 230280.1425, 139: 297507.8831, 140: 67670518.82, 141: 40348580.81, 142: 41532201.95, 143: 38057885.58, 144: 33324313.91, 145: 31598208.66, 146: 35996371.47, 147:
66960494.46, 148: 43141545.17, 149: 29144593.06, 150: 30631253.99, 151: 62261680.34, 152: 25646928.23, 153: 28755089.53, 154: 28832033.8, 155: 43173013.82, 156: 31733999.71, 157: 36342317.41, 158:
23849480.52, 159: 19928754.04, 160: 20612202.87, 161: 15008649.0, 162: 52157937.13, 163: 27573961.96, 164: 18960315.55, 165: 37863540.7, 166: 18324303.36, 167: 30665073.58, 168: 14221960.57, 169: 38204720.33, 170: 29806344.78, 171: 10990033.2, 172: 33278549.69, 173: 13209835.28, 174: 27776730.85, 175: 24122213.98, 176: 15069136.87, 177: 17482093.4, 178: 11740928.24, 179: 12342518.82, 180: 12918871.46, 181:
13361344.29, 182: 13370594.06, 183: 12294807.03, 184: 17349451.86, 185: 15445722.57, 186: 14158898.22, 187: 11691682.34, 188:
10896945.63, 189: 135341037.6, 190: 80697161.63, 191: 83064403.89, 192: 133920988.9, 193: 86283090.34, 194: 124523360.7, 195:
86346027.65, 196: 104315874.3, 197: 76409440.66}, 'STDDEVI': {0: 5413641.505, 1: 3227886.465, 2: 3322576.156, 3: 3044630.846, 4: 2665945.113, 5: 2527856.693, 6: 2879709.718, 7: 5356839.557, 8: 3451323.613, 9: 2331567.445, 10: 2450500.32, 11: 4980934.427, 12: 2051754.258, 13: 2300407.162, 14: 2306562.704, 15: 3453841.106, 16: 2538719.977, 17: 2907385.393, 18: 1907958.442, 19: 1594300.323, 20: 1648976.23, 21: 1200691.92, 22: 844583.0249, 23: 4172634.97, 24: 2205916.957, 25: 1516825.244, 26: 3029083.256, 27: 1465944.269, 28: 2453205.886, 29: 1137756.845, 30: 813702.7502, 31: 3056377.626, 32: 2384507.582, 33: 879202.656, 34: 534352.1528, 35: 381320.6848, 36: 774631.8928, 37: 2662283.975, 38: 1056786.822, 39: 2222138.468, 40: 1929777.118, 41: 1205530.949, 42: 1398567.472, 43: 939274.2592, 44: 987401.5054, 45: 1033509.717, 46: 291466.2091, 47: 848653.1796, 48: 1068907.543, 49: 1069647.525, 50: 460593.9475, 51: 718149.6505, 52: 983584.5625, 53: 1387956.149, 54: 667389.7432, 55: 545294.2504, 56: 1235657.806, 57: 574240.7888, 58: 683869.36, 59: 566566.9876, 60: 1132711.858, 61: 717172.2206, 62: 746807.9859, 63: 637585.293, 64: 935334.5869, 65: 840485.8264, 66: 165053.0424, 67: 410172.6428, 68: 509790.6353, 69: 871755.6503, 70: 508758.7608, 71: 627455.4913, 72: 747372.9772, 73: 366711.3959, 74: 438056.8973, 75: 204078.4913, 76: 681809.2841, 77: 736072.5366, 78: 697352.1752, 79: 715058.5301, 80: 609416.5868, 81: 713832.5418, 82: 564474.3333, 83: 657662.8285, 84: 461949.9519, 85: 54835.65849, 86: 594022.6875, 87: 475118.6252, 88: 433918.5269, 89: 489151.4948, 90: 230654.059, 91: 168772.5118, 92: 303554.1375, 93: 624024.0593, 94: 381784.5097, 95: 189877.4875, 96: 111071.1313, 97: 349924.2887, 98: 327059.3317, 99: 253221.5283, 100: 330036.8114, 101: 292033.5338, 102: 321389.2409, 103: 302479.4595, 104: 268242.5032, 105: 178877.4313, 106: 233811.8894, 107:
245697.1723, 108: 73834.79179, 109: 192070.77, 110: 204575.946, 111: 127473.3322, 112: 141543.3775, 113: 186663.5597, 114: 178118.0695, 115: 162525.8992, 116: 134299.7015, 117: 129758.0252, 118: 147600.0, 119: 131898.1107, 120: 137097.3375, 121: 123943.5713, 122:
90742.90254, 123: 115484.286, 124: 228527.4122, 125: 101113.5457, 126: 101935.1807, 127: 100284.4859, 128: 72580.11363, 129: 81549.94411, 130: 85394.21633, 131: 56295.43605, 132: 84919.7845, 133: 80267.28067, 134: 72685.40692, 135: 73133.4933, 136: 61290.23344, 137: 45000.0, 138: 46056.02851, 139: 59501.57661, 140: 16917629.7, 141: 10087145.2, 142: 10383050.49, 143: 9514471.395, 144: 8331078.477, 145:
7899552.165, 146: 8999092.868, 147: 16740123.61, 148: 10785386.29, 149: 7286148.264, 150: 7657813.499, 151: 15565420.08, 152:
6411732.056, 153: 7188772.382, 154: 7208008.45, 155: 10793253.46, 156: 7933499.928, 157: 9085579.353, 158: 5962370.131, 159: 4982188.51, 160: 5153050.718, 161: 3752162.25, 162: 13039484.28, 163: 6893490.491, 164: 4740078.888, 165: 9465885.174, 166: 4581075.841, 167: 7666268.394, 168: 3555490.142, 169: 9551180.082, 170: 7451586.195, 171: 2747508.3, 172: 8319637.422, 173: 3302458.819, 174: 6944182.712, 175:
6030553.494, 176: 3767284.217, 177: 4370523.349, 178: 2935232.06, 179: 3085629.704, 180: 3229717.864, 181: 3340336.073, 182: 3342648.515, 183: 3073701.758, 184: 4337362.965, 185: 3861430.643, 186:
3539724.555, 187: 2922920.584, 188: 2724236.407, 189: 101505778.2, 190: 60522871.22, 191: 62298302.92, 192: 100440741.7, 193:
64712317.75, 194: 93392520.51, 195: 64759520.73, 196: 78236905.69, 197: 57307080.49}, 'STDDEVC': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 0, 26: 0, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 0, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 0, 34: 0, 35: 0, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0, 45: 0, 46: 0, 47: 0, 48: 0, 49: 0, 50: 0, 51: 0, 52: 0, 53: 0, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 0, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 0, 60: 0, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 0, 64: 0, 65: 0, 66: 0, 67: 0, 68: 0, 69: 0, 70: 0, 71: 0, 72: 0, 73: 0, 74: 0, 75: 0, 76: 0, 77: 0, 78: 0, 79: 0, 80: 0, 81: 0, 82: 0, 83: 0, 84: 0, 85: 0, 86: 0, 87: 0, 88: 0, 89: 0, 90: 0, 91: 0, 92: 0, 93: 0, 94: 0, 95: 0, 96: 0, 97: 0, 98: 0, 99: 0, 100: 0, 101: 0, 102: 0, 103: 0, 104: 0, 105: 0, 106: 0, 107: 0, 108: 0, 109: 0, 110: 0, 111: 0, 112: 0, 113: 0, 114: 0, 115: 0, 116: 0, 117: 0, 118: 0, 119: 0, 120: 0, 121: 0, 122: 0, 123: 0, 124: 0, 125: 0, 126: 0, 127: 0, 128: 0, 129: 0, 130: 0, 131: 0, 132: 0, 133: 0, 134: 0, 135: 0, 136: 0, 137: 0, 138: 0, 139: 0, 140: 0, 141: 0, 142: 0, 143: 0, 144: 0, 145: 0, 146: 0, 147: 0, 148: 0, 149: 0, 150: 0, 151: 0, 152: 0, 153: 0, 154: 0, 155: 0, 156: 0, 157: 0, 158: 0, 159: 0, 160: 0, 161: 0, 162: 0, 163: 0, 164: 0, 165: 0, 166: 0, 167: 0, 168: 0, 169: 0, 170: 0, 171: 0, 172: 0, 173: 0, 174: 0, 175: 0, 176: 0, 177: 0, 178: 0, 179: 0, 180: 0, 181: 0, 182: 0, 183: 0, 184: 0, 185: 0, 186: 0, 187: 0, 188: 0, 189: 0, 190: 0, 191: 0, 192: 0, 193: 0, 194: 0, 195: 0, 196: 0, 197: 0}, 'EXPVALUE': {0: 54136415.06, 1: 32278864.66, 2: 33225761.56, 3: 30446308.46, 4:
26659451.12, 5: 25278566.92, 6: 28797097.18, 7: 53568395.56, 8: 34513236.14, 9: 23315674.44, 10: 24505003.2, 11: 49809344.28, 12: 20517542.58, 13: 23004071.62, 14: 23065627.04, 15: 34538411.06, 16: 25387199.76, 17: 29073853.92, 18: 19079584.42, 19: 15943003.23, 20: 16489762.3, 21: 12006919.2, 22: 8445830.248, 23: 41726349.7, 24: 22059169.58, 25: 15168252.44, 26: 30290832.56, 27: 14659442.69, 28: 24532058.86, 29: 11377568.45, 30: 8137027.502, 31: 30563776.26, 32: 23845075.82, 33: 8792026.56, 34: 5343521.528, 35: 3813206.848, 36: 7746318.928, 37: 26622839.76, 38: 10567868.22, 39: 22221384.68, 40: 19297771.18, 41: 12055309.49, 42: 13985674.72, 43: 9392742.592, 44: 9874015.054, 45: 10335097.17, 46: 2914662.092, 47: 8486531.796, 48: 10689075.43, 49: 10696475.25, 50: 4605939.476, 51: 7181496.504, 52: 9835845.624, 53: 13879561.49, 54: 6673897.432, 55: 5452942.504, 56: 12356578.06, 57: 5742407.888, 58: 6838693.6, 59: 5665669.876, 60: 11327118.58, 61: 7171722.206, 62: 7468079.86, 63: 6375852.93, 64: 9353345.868, 65: 8404858.264, 66: 1650530.424, 67: 4101726.428, 68: 5097906.352, 69: 8717556.502, 70: 5087587.608, 71: 6274554.912, 72: 7473729.772, 73: 3667113.958, 74: 4380568.974, 75: 2040784.914, 76: 6818092.842, 77: 7360725.366, 78: 6973521.752, 79: 7150585.3, 80: 6094165.868, 81: 7138325.418, 82: 5644743.334, 83: 6576628.284, 84: 4619499.52, 85: 548356.585, 86: 5940226.874, 87: 4751186.252, 88: 4339185.27, 89: 4891514.948, 90: 2306540.59, 91: 1687725.118, 92: 3035541.376, 93: 6240240.592, 94: 3817845.098, 95: 1898774.875, 96: 1110711.313, 97: 3499242.886, 98: 3270593.318, 99: 2532215.282, 100: 3300368.114, 101: 2920335.338, 102: 3213892.41, 103: 3024794.594, 104: 2682425.032, 105: 1788774.313, 106: 2338118.894, 107: 2456971.724, 108: 738347.9178, 109: 1920707.7, 110: 2045759.46, 111: 1274733.322, 112: 1415433.775, 113: 1866635.597, 114: 1781180.695, 115:
1625258.992, 116: 1342997.015, 117: 1297580.252, 118: 1476000.0, 119: 1318981.107, 120: 1370973.375, 121: 1239435.713, 122: 907429.0254, 123: 1154842.86, 124: 2285274.122, 125: 1011135.457, 126: 1019351.807, 127: 1002844.859, 128: 725801.1364, 129: 815499.4412, 130:
853942.1634, 131: 562954.3604, 132: 849197.845, 133: 802672.8066, 134: 726854.0692, 135: 731334.933, 136: 612902.3344, 137: 450000.0, 138: 460560.285, 139: 595015.7662, 140: 135341037.6, 141: 80697161.62, 142: 83064403.9, 143: 76115771.16, 144: 66648627.82, 145: 63196417.32, 146: 71992742.94, 147: 133920988.9, 148: 86283090.34, 149: 58289186.12, 150: 61262507.98, 151: 124523360.7, 152: 51293856.46, 153:
57510179.06, 154: 57664067.6, 155: 86346027.64, 156: 63467999.42, 157: 72684634.82, 158: 47698961.04, 159: 39857508.08, 160: 41224405.74, 161: 30017298.0, 162: 104315874.3, 163: 55147923.92, 164: 37920631.1, 165: 75727081.4, 166: 36648606.72, 167: 61330147.16, 168: 28443921.14, 169: 76409440.66, 170: 59612689.56, 171: 21980066.4, 172: 66557099.38, 173: 26419670.56, 174: 55553461.7, 175: 48244427.96, 176: 30138273.74, 177: 34964186.8, 178: 23481856.48, 179: 24685037.64, 180: 25837742.92, 181: 26722688.58, 182: 26741188.12, 183: 24589614.06, 184:
34698903.72, 185: 30891445.14, 186: 28317796.44, 187: 23383364.68, 188: 21793891.26, 189: 270682075.2, 190: 161394323.3, 191:
166128807.8, 192: 267841977.8, 193: 172566180.7, 194: 249046721.4, 195: 172692055.3, 196: 208631748.6, 197: 152818881.3}, 'weight': {0:
0.003861004360956014, 1: 0.003861004360956014, 2: 0.003861004360956014, 3: 0.003861004360956014, 4: 0.003861004360956014, 5: 0.003861004360956014, 6: 0.003861004360956014, 7: 0.003861004360956014, 8: 0.003861004360956014, 9: 0.003861004360956014, 10: 0.003861004360956014, 11: 0.003861004360956014, 12: 0.003861004360956014, 13: 0.003861004360956014, 14: 0.003861004360956014, 15: 0.003861004360956014, 16: 0.003861004360956014, 17: 0.003861004360956014, 18: 0.003861004360956014, 19: 0.003861004360956014, 20: 0.003861004360956014, 21: 0.003861004360956014, 22: 0.003861004360956014, 23: 0.003861004360956014, 24: 0.003861004360956014, 25: 0.003861004360956014, 26: 0.003861004360956014, 27: 0.003861004360956014, 28: 0.003861004360956014, 29: 0.003861004360956014, 30: 0.003861004360956014, 31: 0.003861004360956014, 32: 0.003861004360956014, 33: 0.003861004360956014, 34: 0.003861004360956014, 35: 0.003861004360956014, 36: 0.003861004360956014, 37: 0.003861004360956014, 38: 0.003861004360956014, 39: 0.003861004360956014, 40: 0.003861004360956014, 41: 0.003861004360956014, 42: 0.003861004360956014, 43: 0.003861004360956014, 44: 0.003861004360956014, 45: 0.003861004360956014, 46: 0.003861004360956014, 47: 0.003861004360956014, 48: 0.003861004360956014, 49: 0.003861004360956014, 50: 0.003861004360956014, 51: 0.003861004360956014, 52: 0.003861004360956014, 53: 0.003861004360956014, 54: 0.003861004360956014, 55: 0.003861004360956014, 56: 0.003861004360956014, 57: 0.003861004360956014, 58: 0.003861004360956014, 59: 0.003861004360956014, 60: 0.003861004360956014, 61: 0.003861004360956014, 62: 0.003861004360956014, 63: 0.003861004360956014, 64: 0.003861004360956014, 65: 0.003861004360956014, 66: 0.003861004360956014, 67: 0.003861004360956014, 68: 0.003861004360956014, 69: 0.003861004360956014, 70: 0.003861004360956014, 71: 0.003861004360956014, 72: 0.003861004360956014, 73: 0.003861004360956014, 74: 0.003861004360956014, 75: 0.003861004360956014, 76: 0.003861004360956014, 77: 0.003861004360956014, 78: 0.003861004360956014, 79: 0.003861004360956014, 80: 0.003861004360956014, 81: 0.003861004360956014, 82: 0.003861004360956014, 83: 0.003861004360956014, 84: 0.003861004360956014, 85: 0.003861004360956014, 86: 0.003861004360956014, 87: 0.003861004360956014, 88: 0.003861004360956014, 89: 0.003861004360956014, 90: 0.003861004360956014, 91: 0.003861004360956014, 92: 0.003861004360956014, 93: 0.003861004360956014, 94: 0.003861004360956014, 95: 0.003861004360956014, 96: 0.003861004360956014, 97: 0.003861004360956014, 98: 0.003861004360956014, 99: 0.003861004360956014, 100: 0.003861004360956014, 101: 0.003861004360956014, 102: 0.003861004360956014, 103: 0.003861004360956014, 104: 0.003861004360956014, 105: 0.003861004360956014, 106: 0.003861004360956014, 107: 0.003861004360956014, 108: 0.003861004360956014, 109: 0.003861004360956014, 110: 0.003861004360956014, 111: 0.003861004360956014, 112: 0.003861004360956014, 113: 0.003861004360956014, 114: 0.003861004360956014, 115: 0.003861004360956014, 116: 0.003861004360956014, 117: 0.003861004360956014, 118: 0.003861004360956014, 119: 0.003861004360956014, 120: 0.003861004360956014, 121: 0.003861004360956014, 122: 0.003861004360956014, 123: 0.003861004360956014, 124: 0.003861004360956014, 125: 0.003861004360956014, 126: 0.003861004360956014, 127: 0.003861004360956014, 128: 0.003861004360956014, 129: 0.003861004360956014, 130: 0.003861004360956014, 131: 0.003861004360956014, 132: 0.003861004360956014, 133: 0.003861004360956014, 134: 0.003861004360956014, 135: 0.003861004360956014, 136: 0.003861004360956014, 137: 0.003861004360956014, 138: 0.003861004360956014, 139: 0.003861004360956014, 140: 0.005515718883454712, 141: 0.005515718883454712, 142: 0.005515718883454712, 143: 0.005515718883454712, 144: 0.005515718883454712, 145: 0.005515718883454712, 146: 0.005515718883454712, 147: 0.005515718883454712, 148: 0.005515718883454712, 149: 0.005515718883454712, 150: 0.005515718883454712, 151: 0.005515718883454712, 152: 0.005515718883454712, 153: 0.005515718883454712, 154: 0.005515718883454712, 155: 0.005515718883454712, 156: 0.005515718883454712, 157: 0.005515718883454712, 158: 0.005515718883454712, 159: 0.005515718883454712, 160: 0.005515718883454712, 161: 0.005515718883454712, 162: 0.005515718883454712, 163: 0.005515718883454712, 164: 0.005515718883454712, 165: 0.005515718883454712, 166: 0.005515718883454712, 167: 0.005515718883454712, 168: 0.005515718883454712, 169: 0.005515718883454712, 170: 0.005515718883454712, 171: 0.005515718883454712, 172: 0.005515718883454712, 173: 0.005515718883454712, 174: 0.005515718883454712, 175: 0.005515718883454712, 176: 0.005515718883454712, 177: 0.005515718883454712, 178: 0.005515718883454712, 179: 0.005515718883454712, 180: 0.005515718883454712, 181: 0.005515718883454712, 182: 0.005515718883454712, 183: 0.005515718883454712, 184: 0.005515718883454712, 185: 0.005515718883454712, 186: 0.005515718883454712, 187: 0.005515718883454712, 188: 0.005515718883454712, 189: 0.021021018241875224, 190: 0.021021018241875224, 191: 0.021021018241875224, 192: 0.021021018241875224, 193: 0.021021018241875224, 194: 0.021021018241875224, 195: 0.021021018241875224, 196: 0.021021018241875224, 197: 0.021021018241875224}})
```

The script generally works well and runs in less than 10 secs or so - however I would like to be able to put in multiple parameters for `xs` and for `lim` and the script starts to become quite slow. Is there any way I can speed it up?

Comment: *multiple parameters for xs and for lim*  - what are max values for `xs` and `lim` supposed in your real case?

Comment: Not sure what `sp` is and what is doing. The only thing at first sight would be to calculate `MU` and `sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"] / sampled_events["EXPVALUE"]` only once... but that alone won't make miracles. Did you profile the execution to find out the bottlenecks? If you have ipython check `%prun` else check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: Since every run takes ~10s and you are iterating ~10000x, if you don't manage to bring the single execution to a "nice" level, you can also use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to paralelize the work performed in your for loop.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - e.g. i will want to run the same thing for `xs = 5e6, 10e6, 15e6` and `lim = 10e6,10e6,10e6`

Comment: @deponovo sorry i did not show the libraries - i've edited my post

Comment: @user33484, you mean you want to apply those larger `xs/lim` pairs of limits sequentially on different runs of smulation?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah exactly

Comment: @user33484, Is the issue still actual or have you solved it?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest same issue so any help would be great

Comment: @user33484 I tried a (most probably wrong at the math level) full vectorized implementation of the problem and the execution time droped down to 750ms. I am not posting it as it is probably flawed from the math point of view... just dropping the exec time here for reference.

Comment: @deponovo - could you post your solution pls? I want to give it an array of `lim` and `xs` and have it run through and I think I need to have it vectorized for the speed (rather than run each one in parallel)

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: Updated the edit with a parametrized `my_v2`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Time reduction from ~14.6s to ~2.2s:

```
raw['a1'] = ( 
    (raw["PERSPVALUE"] / (raw["STDDEVI"]+raw["STDDEVC"]))**2 
    * (1 -raw["PERSPVALUE"]/raw["EXPVALUE"]) 
    - raw["PERSPVALUE"] / raw["EXPVALUE"] 
)

raw['b1'] = raw['a1'] * (raw["EXPVALUE"]/raw["PERSPVALUE"] - 1)

def my_v2(df: pd.DataFrame, _xs: float, _lim: float, _n_simulations: int, _poisson):
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'no_clm': [_poisson.rvs(size=1)[0] for _ in range(_n_simulations)],
            'result[i]': 0.0, # float!
        }
    )
    df_temp = df_temp.loc[df_temp['no_clm'].ne(0)] # remove irrelevant rows... but the original amount of data will be taken into account later when calculating the mean
    df_temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) # just to be nice, not actually necessary
    df_temp['sample_idxs'] = [np.random.choice(df.index, size=s, p=df["weight"]) for s in df_temp['no_clm']]
    # even if looping is bad in terms of performance [see continuation of the comment hereafter]
    for i, (idxs, clm) in enumerate(zip(df_temp['sample_idxs'].values, df_temp['no_clm'].values)):
        sample = df.iloc[idxs]
        df_temp.loc[i, 'result[i]'] = np.clip(
            a=(
                np.array(sp.beta(sample['a1'], sample['b1']).rvs(clm) * sample["EXPVALUE"])  # clm_sev
                - _xs
            ),
            a_min=0,
            a_max=_lim
        ).sum()
        # [continuation] the calculation above takes 74% of the iteration total time
    return df_temp['result[i]'].sum() / _n_simulations

simulated = my_v2(raw, xs, lim, 10_000, poisson)
```

Please note the above comments in the code. I am not into the math you are doing and maybe there's a better way to obtain and work witj the slices (`sample_idxs`), but a substantial part of the runtime goes into the said math.

Now add multiprocessing to it (1_000_000 simulations took 41s and not 100 * 2.2s):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from functools import partial
    import time
    sim_lazy = partial(my_v2, raw, xs, lim, 10_000)

    start = time.time_ns()
    with Pool(10) as p:  # update value 10 according to CPU count
        sims = p.map(sim_lazy, [poisson]*100)
        print('# sims: ', len(sims))
    end = time.time_ns()
    print(sims)
    print('time[s]: ', (end - start) / 1e9)
```

output:

```
# sims:  100
[1300482.5037604165, 1359875.637012542, 1292862.46851181, 1293683.4521449932, 1327332.2848075998, 1242782.750047064, 1253826.2041659697, 1340886.0813557846, 1326570.2888816157, 1276747.1119014442, 1312805.197129519, 1281474.4677000958, 1276805.6717676532, 1338924.4887676393, 1278635.9061525047, 1266613.2307233817, 1397368.3794324645, 1281408.6604564723, 1293014.3045380807, 1333181.1910116875, 1282850.64400875, 1316421.4618292646, 1311292.5852779138, 1326328.1298790905, 1258097.8688863025, 1301549.2779544205, 1308432.9873687667, 1311391.096930556, 1303397.4027974785, 1323658.6816205857, 1263996.6919505843, 1328781.311900143, 1287033.3553283573, 1307426.1119317347, 1364268.9566384132, 1338835.6746304017, 1291157.7939342086, 1315551.315471422, 1301106.0512130584, 1288101.6127880784, 1338881.5051435642, 1286559.9109840102, 1276747.967904101, 1343546.6561589213, 1289511.4225339014, 1267920.1910362607, 1331851.662608684, 1286997.4340657925, 1259614.7322937471, 1331279.6563895687, 1327149.517418336, 1320832.103970996, 1314437.5801615207, 1259430.8132275275, 1255523.8745606944, 1307944.3579934386, 1289279.4364602964, 1270376.034134319, 1316729.930686142, 1283266.4915991852, 1325922.3334680817, 1318090.2551226635, 1293799.8469699472, 1329849.4194686355, 1325690.8433244496, 1285011.4028365943, 1258927.0517938838, 1313340.6071377331, 1262832.281474432, 1236449.7007668037, 1331015.286921405, 1254097.0481307174, 1282665.1951283433, 1349765.6635568189, 1288104.8160324676, 1280708.2835476983, 1374407.0270103973, 1304568.357228136, 1277390.7299957874, 1335803.017898254, 1280194.2316711263, 1288761.2748483815, 1334627.7915116576, 1343523.551611712, 1284816.6154147899, 1383905.400323973, 1318321.6018813767, 1258792.6176652717, 1334880.546581696, 1246190.214715553, 1356516.955149957, 1377748.4834818265, 1283673.0978938187, 1299744.43409977, 1347214.626457318, 1273494.4010494335, 1282556.9667627707, 1329775.6474787956, 1321706.5009008243, 1243900.5655492698]
time[s]:  43.645233
```

**Disclaimer: modifications to the calculations were performed to achieve a higher level of vectorization**
No idea whether mathematically correct and added at request from OP:

```
def my_v3():
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'no_clm': [poisson.rvs(size=1)[0] for _ in range(n_simulations)],
            'result[i]': 0.0, # float!
        }
    )

    df_temp = df_temp.loc[df_temp['no_clm'].ne(0)]
    df_temp['sample_idxs'] = [np.random.choice(raw.index, size=s, p=raw["weight"]) if s != 0 else 0 for s in df_temp['no_clm']]
    df_temp = df_temp.explode('sample_idxs')
    df_temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    raw_linear = raw.iloc[df_temp['sample_idxs']]
    raw_linear['result[i]'] = np.clip(
            a=(
                np.array(sp.beta(raw_linear['a1'], raw_linear['b1']).rvs() * raw_linear["EXPVALUE"])  # clm_sev
                - xs
            ),
            a_min=0,
            a_max=lim
        )
    raw_linear['result[i]'] = raw_linear['result[i]'].values / df_temp['no_clm'].values

    return raw_linear['result[i]'].sum() / n_simulations
```

**Original:**
As I mentioned in my comments, this is a question of profiling your code and find the bottlenecks.

I found a significant one and the execution time on single execution (single thread) decreased by ~5x. Here are the relevant modifications:

```py
MU = np.sum(raw["RATE"])
raw["weight"] = raw["RATE"] / MU

poisson = sp.poisson(mu=MU)
n_simulations = 10000
xs = 5e6
lim = 10e6

def my():
    result = np.empty((n_simulations))
    for i in range(n_simulations):
        no_clm = poisson.rvs(size=1)
    
        # note this decision !
        if no_clm[0] == 0:
            result[i] = 0
            continue
    
        # simulate beta distribution
    
        sampled_events = raw.sample(n=no_clm, weights=raw["weight"])
    
        # calculate params for beta distribution
        fac = sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"] / sampled_events["EXPVALUE"]
        a_1 = ( 
            (sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"] / (sampled_events["STDDEVI"]+sampled_events["STDDEVC"])) ** 2
            * (1 - fac) - fac 
        )

        # simulate from said distribution
        clm_sev = np.array(
            sp.beta(a_1, a_1 * (1/fac - 1)).rvs(no_clm) 
            * sampled_events["EXPVALUE"]
        )
    
        # apply features
        xol_loss = np.clip(a=clm_sev - xs, a_min=0, a_max=lim)
    
        # store result
        result[i] = xol_loss.sum()
    
    return result.mean()
```

if you now combine it with multiprocessing, as previously suggested by me and also shown in an answer by another contributor, you can get your work done even faster if you need to repeat this over and over again.

Additional note: the `sample` method is a performance intensive one in your snippet. Maybe you can find a more alternative method or strategy to achieve the same result.

Comment: Agree. But if the dataframe remains this small, that should not be such a great deal. Anyway, I think one can certainly optimize the algorithm further and exploit vectorization. In the end none of the loops require information of each other, hence it is an [Embarrassingly parallel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)

Comment: When running your `my_v2()` function throws `KeyError: 'a1'`

Comment: Added edit with `a1` and `b1` columns.

Comment: not for nitpicking, but for fairness and correctness: `a1` and `b1` are supposed to be calculated for each separate dataframe sample per each non-zero simulation, while you made that calculation just once and moved it outside. Another thing is that the requirement says:  "*Effectively want to run this script for **1m** simulations rather than 10,000 ...*". Your 1st phrase "Time reduction from ~14.6s to ~2.2s" is particularly for 10_000.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the calculation of 'a1' and 'b1' data is not different whether you make it in the loop or at the dataframe level, hence moved it outside for performance, which it is all this is about. For the second part I agree.

Comment: My bad, I was missed that vectorized case. You did good in that aspect.

Comment: Could you please explain how your pool code does 1m sims? it looks like it does 10,000 sims only?

Comment: 100x`my_v2`, each `my_v2` call runs 10'000 sims. In your question you average everything at the end, hence the approach should be legitimate?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting your requirement

> Effectively want to run this script for **1m** simulations rather than
> 10,000 ...

I focus on that target workload.
Let's move gradually in stages.

- Calculating `a`, `b` shape parameters

  As was previously suggested, instead of calculating on each simulation, those can be calculated and established just once in a vectorized manner on the dataframe level. @deponovo did a good optimization on that aspect. 
  On this stage a small optimization tip is eliminating repetitive calculations like `raw["PERSPVALUE"]/raw["EXPVALUE"]` moving them to a variable. Logically move this into a separate function like below:

---

```
def set_shape_params(df):
    """Calculate shape (a, b) params for beta distribution and set them into df"""
    pers_expt_ratio = df["PERSPVALUE"] / df["EXPVALUE"]
    df['a'] = ((df["PERSPVALUE"] / (df["STDDEVI"] + df["STDDEVC"])) ** 2
               * (1 - pers_expt_ratio) - pers_expt_ratio)

    df['b'] = df['a'] * (df["EXPVALUE"] / df["PERSPVALUE"] - 1)
```

- Sampling the dataframe

  Basing on the previous stage, `df.sample` becomes inactual, so we shift to sampling on dataframe index to find `a`/`b` params. In fact, `df.sample` in its deep source code relies on `np.random.RandomState.choice` call, so it basically can be imitated by `np.random.choice`. But, using `numpy.random.Generator` object (instantiated by [`numpy.random.default_rng`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng)) is a recommended and preferable way.
- `Scipy` functions

  Even resorting to vectorization and filtering out zero simulations, the workload of 1M remains with perceptible delay. 
  The most expensive and time-delaying in this processing are `scipy` routines calls.
  Instead of plucking out by one single element with `sp.poisson(mu=MU).rvs(size=1)` we can draw a sample from a Poisson distribution for the entire workload `N=1000_000` with:

  ```
  no_clms = poisson.rvs(size=N)
  ```

  Practically, when you compare the results of `np.array([sp.poisson(mu=MU).rvs(size=1)[0] for i in range(100)])` and `sp.poisson(mu=MU).rvs(size=100)` you'll note that the "goodness" of random distribution is quite similar.
- Consider only *"non-zero"* simulations:

  ```
  no_clms = no_clms[no_clms != 0]
  ```
- Exposure of [`sp.beta`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html)`.rvs`

  In your current approach you're using `sp.beta(a, b).rvs(no_clm)` call. The issue is that the 1st part `sp.beta(a, b)` returns a *"frozen"* RV object holding the given parameters fixed. But since we need an immediate distributed random variates we'd apply: **`sp.beta.rvs(a, b, size=no_clm)`**. 
  That makes it running more than an order of magnitude faster!

Ok, say we've adopted all the above optimization tips but still not satisfied by a duration of 1M simulations running sequentially.
In this position I'd take advantage of [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to run numerical computations in parallel. 
Declaring a target function for a simulation called by a process [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) in a separate worker, and since in my version the input dataframe is accessed only for reading data (within a worker), the global access to it (without pickling) is organized via `initializer/initargs` parameters.

The full code:

```
# Optimizing simulations with sp.beta distributions

import time
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as sp
from numpy.random import default_rng


def init_worker(shared_df):
    global df
    df = shared_df


def set_shape_params(df):
    """Calculate shape (a, b) params for beta distribution and set them into df"""
    pers_expt_ratio = df["PERSPVALUE"] / df["EXPVALUE"]
    df['a'] = ((df["PERSPVALUE"] / (df["STDDEVI"] + df["STDDEVC"])) ** 2
               * (1 - pers_expt_ratio) - pers_expt_ratio)

    df['b'] = df['a'] * (df["EXPVALUE"] / df["PERSPVALUE"] - 1)


def sim_beta_dist(xs, lim, no_clm):
    """Simulate beta distribution for a given params"""
    global df

    # get random sample by df indices
    rng = default_rng()
    sample = df.loc[rng.choice(df.index, size=no_clm, p=df["weight"]), ['a', 'b', 'EXPVALUE']]

    clm_sev = (sp.beta.rvs(sample['a'].values, sample['b'].values, size=no_clm)
               * sample["EXPVALUE"].values)

    # apply features
    xol_loss_sum = np.clip(a=clm_sev - xs, a_min=0, a_max=lim).sum()
    return xol_loss_sum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv("ELT_RawData.csv")

    MU = np.sum(df["RATE"])
    df["weight"] = df["RATE"] / MU

    poisson = sp.poisson(mu=MU)

    N = 1000_000
    xs = 15e6
    lim = 10e6

    time_start = time.time()

    set_shape_params(df)
    no_clms = poisson.rvs(size=N)
    no_clms = no_clms[no_clms != 0]

    with Pool(processes=cpu_count(), initializer=init_worker, initargs=(df,)) as pool:
        result = sum(pool.map(partial(sim_beta_dist, xs, lim), no_clms)) / N

    time_spent = time.time() - time_start
    print(f'Mean: {result}')
    print(f'Time: {time_spent}')
```

Comment: I seem to keep getting the error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'init_worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>` when i run this

Comment: @user33484, such an error may emerge on Windows and n IPython env. Check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror. Try to move the definition of `init_worker` into `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` section, above Pool creation. Otherwise switch to https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The expression `no_clm = poisson.rvs(size=1)` is 0 more than half of the time (on your data). Which means you can skip the calculation in this case. The below diff sped up the computation from about 20 sec on my machine to 5.8.

```
diff --git a/sim.py b/sim.py
index c4dd0c5..5b4a006 100644
--- a/sim.py
+++ b/sim.py
@@ -50,10 +50,12 @@ n_simulations = 10000
 xs = 5e6
 lim = 10e6
 
-result = np.empty((n_simulations))
+result = np.zeros((n_simulations))
 
 for i in range(n_simulations):
     no_clm = poisson.rvs(size=1)
+    if no_clm[0] == 0:
+        continue
     
     #simulate beta distribution
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have profiled your code and made whatever improvements you can, you could then use multiprocessing to run the simulations in parallel:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.stats as sp

def init_pool(*args):
    global raw

    raw = args[0]

n_simulations = 10000

def compute(xs, lim):
    MU = np.sum(raw["RATE"])
    poisson = sp.poisson(mu=MU)

    result = np.empty((n_simulations))

    for i in range(n_simulations):
        no_clm = poisson.rvs(size=1)

        #simulate beta distribution

        sampled_events = raw.sample(n=no_clm,weights=raw["weight"])

        #calculate params for beta distribution
        a_1 = ( (sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"] / (sampled_events["STDDEVI"]+sampled_events["STDDEVC"]))**2*(1 - sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"]/sampled_events["EXPVALUE"]) - \
                 sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"] / sampled_events["EXPVALUE"] )

        b_1 = a_1*(sampled_events["EXPVALUE"]/sampled_events["PERSPVALUE"]-1)

        #simulate from said distribution
        clm_sev = np.array(sp.beta(a_1,b_1).rvs(no_clm)*sampled_events["EXPVALUE"])

        #apply features
        xol_loss = np.clip(a=clm_sev-xs,a_min=0,a_max=lim)

        #store result
        result[i] = xol_loss.sum()

    return result.mean()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    from  multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

    raw = pd.read_csv("ELT_RawData.csv")
    raw["weight"] = raw["RATE"] / np.sum(raw["RATE"])

    args = ((5e6, 10e6), (10e6,  10e6), (15e6, 10e6))

    with Pool(
        min(cpu_count(), len(args)),
        initializer=init_pool,
        initargs=(raw,)
    ) as pool:
        t = time.time()
        results = pool.starmap(compute, args)
        elapsed = time.time() - t
        print(results)
        print(elapsed)
```

On my desktop running a single simulation takes approximately 33.5 seconds. The above code running 3 simulations in parallel took approximately 38 seconds.

The output:

```None
[1299586.0488044703, 992862.8902988579, 843492.5913153775]
37.97074556350708
```

Comment: The requirement says: "*Effectively want to run this script for **1m** simulations rather than 10,000 ...*"